# How to get session value in the custom class library in Core MVC application

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on the different layers in MVC .net core 3 project. My problem is my controllers and views are in one layer and all the services which perform db related actions is in other class library layer. I want to get the session values in my service layer. How can I get them? I tried HttpContext in service layer but didn't work.

Here is my Controller.

```
namespace CRM.Web.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ContactController : Controller
    {
        private int UserID { get { return Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserID")); } }
        private string RoleName { get { return HttpContext.Session.GetString("RoleName"); } }

        private readonly ContactService _contactService;

        public ContactController(ContactService contactService)
        {
            _contactService = contactService;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Contact Service.

```
namespace CRM.Service.Services.ContactService
{
    public class ContactService : IRepository<Contact>, IDisposable
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        private readonly _DbContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public ContactService(_DbContext context, AutoMapperConfig autoMapperConfig)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = autoMapperConfig.Mapper;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current` Should give you access to the current sessions HttpContext, however I'd advise against using this in your class library if you plan on expanding your application at all, by using session explicit variables within your service layer you're essentially making it so that it can only ever be used as a web app (If you have no plans to use it for anything else then by all means go for it).

If the current session variables arent required for the initialization that class, use a setter method to provide the data, this way you can either provide it the vars needed from session, or if using in a non web capacity, you can pass it the equivalent vars from an alternative source.

Comment: Can you explain it through code? In which layer I have to create session explicit variables and how?

Comment: I wasn't saying you should make explicit variables, you can use "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[variable name]" to access the session variables in your service layer but this is bad practice, instead you should pass the variables into your service layer using methods so only your UI ever needs Session